# K8s Helm - Jenkins with Nginx Ingress

Tags: nginx, jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to deploy Jenkins that is fronted by an nginx-ingress via Helm. The goal is to secure Jenkins behind HTTPs with SSL termination at nginx.
I'm currently using a self-signed cert but will eventually use cert-manager and LetsEncrypt. Jenkins and Nginx-Ingress are deployed in the default namespace.

Below is my deployment script:

```
gcloud config set compute/zone us-central1-f

gcloud container clusters create jenkins-cd \
  --machine-type n1-standard-2 --num-nodes 2 \
  --scopes "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/projecthosting,storage-rw,cloud-platform"

wget https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-helm/helm-v2.9.1-linux-amd64.tar.gz
tar zxfv helm-v2.9.1-linux-amd64.tar.gz
cp linux-amd64/helm .

kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin --user=xxxx@xxxx.com
kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-admin-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller

openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /tmp/tls.key -out /tmp/tls.crt -subj "/CN=xx.xx.xxxx.com"
kubectl create secret tls jenkins-ingress-ssl --key /tmp/tls.key --cert /tmp/tls.crt
kubectl describe secret jenkins-ingress-ssl

./helm init --service-account=tiller --wait
./helm update
./helm install --name nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress --set rbac.create=true
./helm install --name jenkins stable/jenkins --values values.yaml --version 0.19.0 --wait

ADMIN_PWD=$(kubectl get secret --namespace default cd-jenkins -o jsonpath="{.data.jenkins-admin-password}" | base64 --decode)
```

Below is my values.yaml file:

```
Master:
  InstallPlugins:
    - kubernetes:1.12.6
    - workflow-job:2.24
    - workflow-aggregator:2.5
    - credentials-binding:1.16
    - git:3.9.1
    - google-oauth-plugin:0.6
    - google-source-plugin:0.3
  Cpu: "1"
  Memory: "3500Mi"
  JavaOpts: "-Xms3500m -Xmx3500m"
  ServiceType: ClusterIP
  HostName: "xx.xx.xxxx.com"
  Ingress:
    Annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
      kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"    
    TLS:
      - secretName: jenkins-ingress-ssl
        hosts:
          - xx.xx.xxxx.com
Agent:
  Enabled: true
Persistence:
  Size: 100Gi
NetworkPolicy:
  ApiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
rbac:
  install: true
  serviceAccountName: cd-jenkins
```

Deployments (default namespace)

```
xxx@cloudshell:~/stub-jenkins2.0 (automation-stub)$ kubectl get deployments
NAME                            DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
jenkins                         1         1         1            1           6m
nginx-ingress-controller        1         1         1            1           6m
nginx-ingress-default-backend   1         1         1            1           6m
```

Services (default namespace)

```
xxx@cloudshell:~/stub-jenkins2.0 (automation-stub)$ kubectl get services
NAME                            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP       PORT(S)                      AGE
jenkins                         ClusterIP      10.11.240.123   <none>            8080/TCP                     7m
jenkins-agent                   ClusterIP      10.11.250.174   <none>            50000/TCP                    7m
kubernetes                      ClusterIP      10.11.240.1     <none>            443/TCP                      8m
nginx-ingress-controller        LoadBalancer   10.11.253.104   104.198.179.176   80:31453/TCP,443:32194/TCP   7m
nginx-ingress-default-backend   ClusterIP      10.11.245.149   <none>            80/TCP                       7m
```

Ingress (default namespace)

```
xxx@cloudshell:~/stub-jenkins2.0 (automation-stub)$ kubectl get ingress
NAME      HOSTS                      ADDRESS         PORTS     AGE
jenkins   xx.xx.xxxx.com             35.193.17.244   80, 443   7m
```

Ingress .yaml (generated by helm)

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  creationTimestamp: 2018-10-19T17:35:16Z
  generation: 1
  name: jenkins
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "845"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses/jenkins
  uid: 57b76091-d3c5-11e8-b9e9-42010a8001de
spec:
  rules:
  - host: xx.xx.xxxx.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: jenkins
          servicePort: 8080
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - xx.xx.xxxx.com
    secretName: jenkins-ingress-ssl
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 35.193.17.244
```

When hitting the ingress IP (https://104.198.179.176), I hit the default nginx backend service with a "default backend - 404" error. 
I suspect there might be something wrong with the ingress configuration. According to the ingress setup, there is the incorrect
ingress IP (35.193.17.244) whereas the nginx-ingress-controller IP is 104.198.179.176.

Answer (score 3):

If you hit the nginx ingress with `https://104.198.179.176` you will always hit the default backend. You either need to hit it with `https://xx.xx.xxxx.com` or with something like this:

```
$ curl -H 'Host: xx.xx.xxxx.com' https://104.198.179.176
```

With respect to the ingress IP address being incorrect, I would check that your backend service has endpoints and that each is listening on port `8080`.

```
$ kubectl describe svc jenkins
```

or/and

```
$ kubectl describe ep
```

I would also check the events in the Ingress:

```
$ kubectl describe ingress jenkins
```

Finally, I would check the logs in the ingress controller:

```
$ kubectl logs nginx-ingress-controller
```

Comment: Rico - thanks for providing the commands above. I was receiving the following error: `W1022 15:47:41.300320       9 controller.go:824] Service "default/jenkins" does not have any active Endpoint.`however, the Jenkins service clearly has an endpoint defined `Endpoints:         10.8.1.8:8080`. It turns out the guide I was following was using an RBAC service account that was miss-configured. I disabled RBAC on jenkins and nginx and routing worked. Is it essential to configure RBAC on the cluster? I have not worked with this yet. Need to look into it.

Comment: It's not essential but it's recommended in prod for security purposes and separation of privileges.